# How do you explain the usage of "with"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

I'm looking for a logical explanation of how we use the preposition "with" in the following context:

> The company took the first place with their competition a distant second.
>
> North America had the greatest number of travellers over the 5-year
> period with Central and Eastern Europe showing a similar pattern.

I suppose my main question is how do I explain the phrase (it's not a clause) that follows the "with"? and how do I explain the function of "with" in these sentences?

Comment: *with* means accompanying here, making the prepositional phrase an adverbial one of manner telling us how the company won first place.

Comment: These look like examples of coordination where the preposition "with" has a meaning similar to the coordinator “and”. In your first example, the second coordinate is a verbless clause; cf _their competition being a distant second_. In your second example, the second coordinate is clearly a subordinate non-finite clause.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the "verbless clause" and "subordinate non-finite clause". The missing verb is what is causing me confusion.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's strange I can't find a duplicate and I believe there is one. I will try my best to explain it, but it is not easy.

The preposition [with](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with) has a very important function as the below definition indicates:

> used as a *function word* to indicate an **attendant** **fact** or **circumstance**: '*He stood there with his hat on*'

The attendant circumstance means an **accompanying** circumstance. In other words, the action (or state) described after "with" is happening at the same time (usually).

The example in the block quote above could be rephrased to:

> He stood there and he was wearing (on) his hat at the time (he was standing).

Your examples:

> The company took the first place and their competition took a distant
>   second (at the time the company took the first place).
>
> North America had the greatest number of travelers over the 5 year
>   period and Central and Eastern Europe showed a similar pattern (at the
>   time North America had the greatest number of travelers...)

When you have something, you are with something. If two things happen at the same time, one thing is happening **with** the other.

Some more examples:

> The matter was resolved **with** both countries cooperating.
>
> She sat silently **with** the cat dozing at her feet.
>
> The man is leaning against the wall **with** his arms folded.

You need to read as many examples as possible and get yourself familiarized with them.

Comment: @BillJ The sentence I rephrased has "and" in it. If it is explained that way, you can't explain how the verb form is changed to a non-finite form such as "being" and "taking". I agree with you.

Comment: Interestingly, the Cambridge dictionary also defines this use of "with" as meaning "and": [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with) (9th example). I should have given a better reconstruction with a 'verbed' clause, which  might be _and their competition came in a distant second_.

Comment: Thanks Rathony. I'll look into the non-finite clause. That's what's causing the confusion. I'll do some digging into this but if you know any good references or key search terms off the top of your head, I'd really appreciate it! It's the verbless phrase after that is confusing me, or going from the "and"+ clause to a "with"+verbless clause.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In my MA thesis, [The English preposition WITH](http://linguistics.osu.edu/sites/linguistics.osu.edu/files/osu_wpl_01_sm.pdf), pp. 60-, I described this "with" as expressing the subject of an absolute "be" sentence.  I take absolute constructions as subordinate clauses with the precise adverbial relationship to the main clause left unspecified.