# How to identify whether commas is required to separate prepositional phrases at the end of sentence? Why commas hve been used here?

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases

Skims benefited from a well-timed introduction of pajamas and loungewear, [commas]with product lines such as the “cozy collection” bolstering sales as women have traded form-fitting styles for sweatpants.

Ms. Kardashian West said she was deeply involved in Skims, [comma]from helping to design fabrics and collections to picking photographers for product shoots to studying sales data.

[source](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/09/business/dealbook/kardashian-skims.html)

Comment: The first sentence has, after the independent clause, ['with' + absolute construction] (see ['with + absolute phrase'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356641/with-absolute-phrase)). A comma is usually used in such sentences, especially with such a long sentence. // The second example is not strictly grammatical. But adding 'in [every aspect of work at] Skims', the comma is a welcome aid to parsing (and breathing when read aloud).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're quite right as usual, Edwin, but don't you agree that changing the last 'to' to 'and' giving "and studying sales data" would improve the sentence and correct the grammar?

Comment: @BoldBen I'd expect '... [in] all A's, from X to Y' to show hypernym ... hyponyms structure. 'An expert in driving all cars, from bubble cars to F1's' // ' ... in every aspect of work, from scribbling the raw wool to packaging.' //// The 'from X to Y[,] to Z' broadening' is unusual but quite acceptable. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/from_a_to_b): ‘It must also be rather boring and predictable sailing directly and single-mindedly from A to B to C.’ // [Grammar Exchange](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/range-from-business-meetings-to-tutoring-to-reading-discussions).

Comment: ... has a non-spatial usage: '"For instance, these activities range from business meetings to tutoring to reading discussions." Which it OKs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Point taken, I concede!