# Grammar: Participle clause after preposition

Tags: participles

I have been studying the book named Grammar and Vocabulary for Advanced by Martin Hewings and Simon Haines. There is a exercise sentence like this "With the wind reaching hurricane force, ships have been advised to head for land."

As I cannot rewrite the sentence, I'm confused. Could you rewrite the sentence above and clarify it for me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean _give a paraphrase_? 'As the wind is reaching hurricane force, ships have been advised to head for land.' Both variants may have with/as = 'now that [the wind is reaching]' or, more likely, 'because [the wind is reaching]'. The first clause is arguably an absolute clause with a preposition; dropping the preposition makes little difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you explain the usage of "with"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322781/how-do-you-explain-the-usage-of-with) (@Greg Lee's answer and linked thesis).

Comment: Yes, I meant paraphrase. So,"with" in this case is just like a word to introduce the reason (with the wind reaching.......= as/because the wind is reaching.......), isn't it?

Comment: Thanks so much !